# How to Resolve The SSL connection could not be established exception Without ByPass

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ssl, httpclient

I Create a HttpClient and send a request web to web and I got this exception

> "The SSL connection could not be established"

*this code bypass the exception but **I dont want to use this trick on production.***

```
UseDefaultCredentials = true;
ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };
```

When I use refit interface for api I dont get any exception, I need to request web to web too.
Why I get this exception how could I establish SSL?

Comment: I did not understand "_When I use refit interface_". Check this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44953894/how-can-you-verify-validity-of-an-https-ssl-certificate-in-net), looks like it could help you. Personal note: I do totally agree on not using that into production ;-)

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare headers in the first request with working and non working code.  Make the headers in c# like headers in working app.  The default headers in c# are different.

Comment: Are you on a Azure Linux app service plan? If so, it could be that the OpenSSL layer rejects the connection because your certificate is too weak.

Comment: @Métoule I use windows server my application on iis

Comment: @bradbury9 no there is a no solution in there, I guess my problem is different thnx